# UILabel to NSString to load webview

Tags: nsstring, webview, uilabel, nsurl, nsurlrequest

So I have this code, where I am sending a variable storyLink to a label and display it in the specified nib. So far the label displays the text which is what I want. But I want to use that text as an url for a webview. urlString = nothing as of right now because I can't figure out how to use/convert an UILabel to a String suitable for a webview url. So if that was confusing basically I want to take the text stored in my label and use it for the url in my webview. Can someone help?

TestView.h

```
@interface TestView : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    NSString *urlString;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *urlString;

@end
```

TestView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    label.text=nil;
    urlString=something;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];

}
```

sending code

```
TestView *objFirstController=[[[TestView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objFirstController animated:YES];
        objFirstController.label.text=storyLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting properties that are accessed during 'viewDidLoad', make sure to put them before you use pushViewController.

TestView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    label.text=urlString;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}
```

sending code

```
TestView *objFirstController = [[[TestView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
objFirstController.urlString = storyLink;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objFirstController animated:YES];
```